# Tomcat 8.0.33 throwing org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error processing request

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Randomly any tomcat server behind a LB is throwing multiple errors in **catalina.out** causing **response mismatch between the response sent from application and response sent from LB to the requesting client.**

Even the timestamp of response sent from application server is after the response sent from LB to requesting client.

Based on few threads and open bugs on tomcat 7.x these were fixed in 8.5.x versions, not sure though.

Is the same fix available on 8.0.33 versions? Or what can be the cause of these issues.

Sample of logs at catalina.out :

````
1. org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error processing request
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:571)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1070)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.run(Nio2Endpoint.java:1029)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)```

2. java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getRequestURL(Request.java:2254)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getRequestURL(RequestFacade.java:867)```

3. org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled Encountered a non-recycled response and recycled it forcedly.
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter$RecycleRequiredException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled(CoyoteAdapter.java:714)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.recycle(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1832)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.release(Http11Nio2Protocol.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:771)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1070)
````

Comment: Maybe your Tomcat is just [requesting assisted suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_suicide) because you won't just [let it die](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html). Or, maybe you [got hacked](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-8.html).

Comment: Most likely actual problem: your application is retaining references to a request beyond it's lifetime and causing this confusion. You should enable [façade recycling](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Security) to (a) stop response confusion and (b) help debug your application. Also, upgrade.